# Serialize an array of Avro GenericRecord

Tags: java, avro

I use following code to serialize and deserialize between a list of GenericRecord and bytes:

```
public static byte[] encode(List<GenericRecord> records, Schema schema) throws IOException {
    SpecificDatumWriter<GenericRecord>
        datumWriter =
        new SpecificDatumWriter<>(schema);
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byteArrayOutputStream.reset();
    BinaryEncoder binaryEncoder = new EncoderFactory().binaryEncoder(byteArrayOutputStream, null);
    for(GenericRecord segment: records) {
        datumWriter.write(segment, binaryEncoder);
    }
    binaryEncoder.flush();
    byte[] bytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    return bytes;
}


public static List<GenericRecord>  decode(byte[] recordBytes, Schema schema) throws IOException {
    DatumReader<GenericRecord>
        datumReader =
        new SpecificDatumReader<>(schema);
    ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(recordBytes);
    stream.reset();
    BinaryDecoder binaryDecoder = new DecoderFactory().binaryDecoder(stream, null);
    List<GenericRecord> records = new ArrayList<>();
    while (true) {
        try {
            GenericRecord record = datumReader.read(null, binaryDecoder);
            records.add(record);
        } catch (EOFException e) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return records;
}
```

and I got following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -40
        at org.apache.avro.io.parsing.Symbol$Alternative.getSymbol(Symbol.java:402)
        at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.doAction(ResolvingDecoder.java:290)
        at org.apache.avro.io.parsing.Parser.advance(Parser.java:88)
        at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.readIndex(ResolvingDecoder.java:267)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:155)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readField(GenericDatumReader.java:193)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:183)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:151)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:142)
        at com.yahoo.gup.utils.SerilizationUtils.decode(SerilizationUtils.java:60)
```

Any ideas of the root cause? Am I doing the serialization in the right way?

Comment: The error happens on decode, not encode.  Maybe the serialized data being read is corrupted?  Maybe the input file doesn't contain what you think it contains?

Comment: @JimGarrison it's hard to say. right? error in decode might cause by incorrect encode. anyway, do you know some other ways to do this?

Comment: If I were in this situation I'd get the Avro source and trace into the code to see where it was going into the weeds.